# Reflection vector calculation not working properly

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, vector, linear-algebra

I have set up a sort of a reflection vector simulator here: https://jsfiddle.net/ahvonenj/1re5n8jg/

I am using [Vectorious](https://github.com/mateogianolio/vectorious) for my vector calculations and objects.

The program kind of works:[image]

I am casting rays from the middle of the canvas towards the mouse cursor. I can successfully detect ray intersections with walls and the point of the intersection on the wall (red dots). I am also able to get the middle point of the wall (blue dots). I THINK that when I normalize the middle point vector, that is the normal of the wall.

Here is the part that listens to mouse movement, casts the ray, gets the intersection and tried to calculate the reflection vectors ( I have added some comments regarding the actual calculations for the reflection vector and what I think I am calculating):

```html
Global.$canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e)
{
 var ctx = Global.ctx;

 var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 Global.Mouse = new Vector([e.clientX - rect.left, e.clientY - rect.top]);
 
 var v1 = Vector.subtract(Global.Mouse, Global.Canvas.Center).normalize();
 var mag = Vector.subtract(Global.Canvas.Center, Global.Mouse).magnitude();
 var ray = Vector.scale(v1, mag * 3).add(Global.Canvas.Center);
 
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
 ctx.beginPath();
 
 for(var i = 0; i < Global.Canvas.Walls.length; i++)
 {
  var wall = Global.Canvas.Walls[i];
  
  if(rayIntersectsWith(wall, [Global.Canvas.Center, ray]))
  {
   // x_1' - x_0 = v - 2(v dot ñ)ñ
   // Where ñ = Normal of the wall
   // and v = Vector from center to the point of intersection with the wall
   // http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Reflection.html
  
   // This is the point on wall where the intersection happens
   var point = rayIntersectionPoint(wall, [Global.Canvas.Center, ray])
   
   // This is the full ray cast from center towards the mouse
   var d = ray;
   
   // This (probably) is the vector from center to the intersection point on the wall
   var v = Vector.subtract(point, Global.Canvas.Center);
   
   // This represents the wall vector, or a middle of the wall (blue dot on wall)
   var wallVector = Vector.add(wall[0], wall[1]).scale(0.5);
   
   // This is supposed to be the normal of the wall
   var wallNormal = Vector.normalize(wallVector);
   
   // This is supposed to be the 2(v dot ñ) part of the equation
   var v_dot_n = Vector.dot(v, wallNormal) * 2;
   
   // This is supposed to be the v_dot_n * ñ of the equation
   var v_dot_n_scaled_by_n = Vector.scale(wallNormal, v_dot_n);
   
   // This is supposed to be the v - v_dot_n_scale_by_n part of the equation
   var dot_vector = Vector.subtract(v, v_dot_n_scaled_by_n);
   
   console.log('w1', wall[0].x, wall[0].y, ", w2", wall[1].x, wall[1].y)
   
   var bounceVector = dot_vector

   console.log(wallVector.x, wallVector.y, wallVector.magnitude())   
   console.log(wallNormal.x, wallNormal.y, wallNormal.magnitude())


   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(wallVector.x, wallVector.y, Global.isecRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
   ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.lineWidth = 0;
   ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
   
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(dot_vector.x, dot_vector.y, Global.isecRadius * 1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
   ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.lineWidth = 0;
   ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.lineWidth = 3;
   ctx.strokeStyle = '#00FF00';
   ctx.moveTo(wall[0].x, wall[0].y);
   ctx.lineTo(wall[1].x, wall[1].y);
   ctx.stroke();


   console.log(bounceVector.x, bounceVector.y)

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(bounceVector.x, bounceVector.y, Global.isecRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
   ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.lineWidth = 0;
   ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.lineWidth = 1;
   ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
   ctx.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
   ctx.lineTo(bounceVector.x, bounceVector.y);
   ctx.stroke();

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, Global.isecRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
   ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.lineWidth = 0;
   ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  }
 }
 
 ctx.stroke();
 
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.lineWidth = 1;
 ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.moveTo(Global.Canvas.Center.x, Global.Canvas.Center.y);
    ctx.lineTo(ray.x, ray.y);
 ctx.stroke();
});
```

My calculations are based on equations found here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Reflection.html

But if you try the fiddle, you will notice that the reflection calculations barely work for the angled wall and currently do not work at all for the outside walls, so this is where I need some help.

The equation looks like this:

```
x_1'- x_0 = v - 2(v·ñ)ñ.
```

Where x_1´ - x_0 is the reflection vector from the intersection point of the wall to where ever it should be pointing. Probably the same length as v.

v is the vector from x_1 to the intersection point of the wall, so in my code it is named as v and goes from the center to the wall intersection.

ñ is the normal of the wall.

Rest of the equation should also be commented in my code and the variables named accordingly I hope.

I am a bit confused with the stuff subtracted from v in the equation. v dot ñ returns a scalar, which is then multiplied by 2. However ñ is a vector so 2(v dot ñ) must mean scaling vector ñ by the scalar value of 2(v dot ñ)?

Best guess I have been able to conclude from debugging this thing is that the wall normal is most likely note correctly calculated.

Comment: *"I THINK that when I normalize the middle point vector, that is the normal of the wall."* No, it is not. I know vectors, but I don't know javascript; if you can tell me how to rotate a vector 90 degrees, or construct a vector using X and Y components, I can give you the code that will construct the normal.

Answer (score 1):

From my own Geom library I have.

```
// v1, v2 are Vec 
// reflected vec for line hitting this
// argument line is the line to be reflected
//          retVec is the returned resulting vector.
reflectAsVec : function(line, retVec = new Vec()){  // returns a vector... 
    v2.x = this.p2.x - this.p1.x;
    v2.y = this.p2.y - this.p1.y;
    v1.x = line.p2.x - line.p1.x;
    v1.y = line.p2.y - line.p1.y;
    var len = v1.dot(v2.norm()) * 2;
    retVec.x = v2.x * len - v1.x;
    retVec.y = v2.y * len - v1.y;
    return retVec;
},
```

`this` is a line with two points p1,p2 defining the ends. Note the v2 is normalised for the last two lines calculating the reflected vec.

The function `v2.norm()` converts a Vec to a normalised vector as follows

```
// u is a number
norm : function(){ // normalises this to be a unit length.
    u = Math.hypot(this.x,this.y);
    this.x /= u;
    this.y /= u;
    return this; // returns this 
},
```

And for `v1.dot(vec)`

```
dot : function(vec){  // get the dot product of this and {avec}
    return this.x * vec.x + this.y * vec.y; // returns number
},
```

Once you have the reflected vector you can create the reflected line from the intercept point and the reflected vector.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Interestingly enough, this solution results in exact same situation when ported to my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ahvonenj/n5twygxr/ It kind of works... but not like one would expect it to work, hmm...

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe it's the weird coordinate system where (0, 0) is basically the top left corner, but shouldn't vectors behave properly no matter the base... or maybe I should try adding like (300, 300) or (0, 600) for every vector

Comment: @Piwwoli Yes the coordinate system should not matter. Do you have uniform scale?? But I will check my code just incase there is a typo.

Comment: @Piwwoli I just double checked the code in the answer and it works just fine. I will have a look at your fiddle.

Comment: @Piwwoli Something wrong with the normals for all but the diagonal line in the top left. Make sure all the lines and vectors are unique and not referencing  each other. You may be getting values from a point that are referenced an earlier point.